# Cryptarithm - Interesting Math Problem

Tags: cryptography, cryptarithm

This is a very interesting cryptarithm that I came across in an old textbook of mine. It is named accordingly as a tribute to the late Bob Marley (singer).

Cryptarithm - Tribute to Bob Marley

In the multiplication problem below, each digit has been replaced by a letter. Can you determine the value of each letter?

```
       B O B
     x B O B
-------------
     M E O Y
   M I L O
 M E O Y
-------------
 M A R L E Y
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$B = 3,
O = 5,
M = 1,
A = 2,
R = 4,
L = 6,
E = 0,
Y = 9,
I = 7$$

Answer (score 4):

B × B = Y,
so possibilities there are

```
 B Y
 2 4
 3 9
 4 6
 7 9
 8 4
 9 1
```

O × B = O (O $\neq$ 1)

```
 B O
 2 x
 3 5
 4 x
 7 5
 8 x
 9 5
```

O = 5, B is odd
O + O + (carry ?) = E

```
 B Y O E 
 3 9 5 0
 7 9 5 4
 9 1 5 8
```

Next is M, from B × BOB:

```
 B Y O E M
 3 9 5 0 1
 7 9 5 4 x
 9 1 5 8 x
```

So now we have all we need:

```
        3 5 3
      x 3 5 3
 -------------
      1 0 5 9
    1 7 6 5
  1 0 5 9
--------------
  1 2 4 6 0 9
```

Therefore;

```
 B = 3
 O = 5
 M = 1
 A = 2
 R = 4
 L = 6
 E = 0
 Y = 9
 I = 7
 8 does not appear
```